# writing text which reading and writing only one column

Tags: java, file-io, io

My text this

```
sirket;sehir;ilce;unvan;numara
AKSA SAT VE PAAMA ANM RKET KADY BES;STANBUL;KADIKY;A.S.;1230488;
KER BV SANAY;STANBUL;ZEYTNBURNU;A:S.;308133;
C.E.S.COSKUN MH.N.ELK.DAY.TK.MAL.VE GIDA TC.LTD.T.;HATAY;SKENDERUN;LTD. T.;14947;
ANLU GAZ TCARET VE SANY ANNM RKET KIRIKKALE UBES;KIRIKKALE;KIRIKKALE;A.S.;12519;
BVR GIDA MARİ NAAT TURZM SANAY VE TCARET LTD.T.;STANBUL;LO;LTD:STİ.;239;
ASA AKRLK KMYA SANAY (YALOVA UBES);YALOVA;FTLKKY;A.S.;551484;
WNCOR NXDORF LGSAYR SSTEER A.S.-ESNLER SUES;STANBUL;ESENLER;-;1027;
DESA DER SAN. VE TC.;STANBUL;BAKIRKY;A.S.;1480;
SNTM BLŞM TEKJLER SAN. VE TC;DYARBAKIR;YENEHR;A.S.;1439;
```

ı want change "." character instead of ":" at **only unvan column** which contain A.S. ,LTD.T.,LTD:STİ. etc.When java read text ı delete first line.I give first line for understable.And ı want to write **before changing**, **after changing** But my code has problem it can not write text due to ı think space of at sirket column. How can ı write it.

ı want this output

```
KER BV SANAY;STANBUL;ZEYTNBURNU;A:S.;3083;
KER BV SANAY;STANBUL;ZEYTNBURNU;A.S.;308133;
BULVAR GIDA MAMLLERİ NAAT TURZM SANAY VE TCARET LTD.T.;STANBUL;LO;LTD:STİ.;2149;
BULVAR GIDA MAMLLERİ NAAT TURZM SANAY VE TCARET LTD.T.;STANBUL;LO;LTD.STİ.;239;
```

my code is

```
public class MaliyeBir {

    private static String inputPath = "C:\\deneme\\Maliye.csv";
    private static String outputPath = "C:\\yazdirilan\\YazdirilanMaliye.csv";
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static PrintWriter printWriter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
           Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-9");
           bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

           FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
           Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "ISO-8859-9");
           printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);

           String line;

           while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
               EndeksDegeri eD;
                eD = lineToClass(line);
                if (shouldOutput(eD)) {
                       printWriter.append(classToLine(eD, true));
                       printWriter.append(classToLine(eD, false));       
                   }               
           }

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally {
           try {
               bufferedReader.close();
               printWriter.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

    }

    private static boolean shouldOutput(EndeksDegeri eD) {
       if (!eD.tip.contains(":")) {
           return false;
       }

       return true;
    }

    private static String classToLine(EndeksDegeri eD, boolean original) {
       if (!original) {
           eD.tip = eD.tip.replace(":", ".");
       }

       return eD.sirket.concat(";")
               .concat(eD.sehir).concat(";")
               .concat(eD.ilce).concat(";")
               .concat(eD.tip).concat(";")
               .concat(String.valueOf(eD.numara)
                .concat("\r\n")); 
    }

    private static EndeksDegeri lineToClass(String line) {
       String[] element = line.split(";");

       EndeksDegeri endeksDegeri = new EndeksDegeri();
       endeksDegeri.sirket = element[0];
       endeksDegeri.sehir = element[1];
       endeksDegeri.ilce = element[2];
       endeksDegeri.tip = element[3];
       endeksDegeri.numara = Integer.valueOf(element[4]);

       return endeksDegeri;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a CSV file. Try some CSV parsing library instead of trying to build your own.

Comment: ı convert cst to text. ı use comman csv file so.. it is look like my text

Answer (score 1):

If this is a CSV file, which I can infer from the references to the `csv` file extension in the code, then you are much better off using a CSV parsing library such as [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net), which will do all the hard work of parsing the file for you. You can then manipulate a CSV file object and save the result to the file.

Comment: ı convert to csv to text

Comment: Definitely possible, once you read in the CSV file. You can retrieve values from it and write those in your own format.

Comment: but when ı dont use space at sirket column it write.. ı think problem about space and contain purt but ı could not modulize

Comment: It's a little hard to understand your english. Maybe you could post in Turkish and we could run it through Google Translate.

Comment: ahhaah =) where you understand ı am turkish.. :D ok dude ı want to say..when ı dont use space between word at sirket column it is write.. but there space between word at sirket column so it can not write..

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that no other columns contain the delimiter `;`, you can use Java `split` function to split the text in columns, then use `replace` function to replace the colon into dot, like this:

```
while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    String[] elements = line.split(";");
    if(elements[3].contains(":")){ // If the value in column "ulvan" contains ":"
        printWriter.append(line); // Print the original
        for(int i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            if(i>0){
                printWriter.append(";"); // Print the delimiter
            }
            if(i==3){ // For column index 3, which is "ulvan"
                printWriter.append(elements[i].replace(":",".")); // Replace ':' with '.'
            } else { // For other columns, just print
                printWriter.append(elements[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity I wrote everything in the main function, you can modularize it if you want.

Comment: sory ı can not modularize it to my code :( it has lots of error.. could you put all of part

Comment: ı modularize it but it still dont write :(

Comment: and dont write but when ı take output, it give words by line by